# Ошибка "InvalidParameter calling waveInOpen" при записи звука с микрофона C#

Tags: c#, naudio

Записываю звук с микрофона в файл '*.wav'.
По каким то причинам на некоторых компьютерах код падает на вызове 'waveIn.StartRecording()' с ошибкой 'InvalidParameter calling waveInOpen', хотя оборудование все подключено и доступно, кодеки на компьютере установлены. ('WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveIn.DeviceNumber).ProductName' - выводит как нужное устройство). Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

```
/// <summary>
/// Частота дискретизации
/// </summary>
public readonly int samplingFrequency = 16000;


waveIn = new WaveIn();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(samplingFrequency, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveIn.DeviceNumber).Channels);
waveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable);
waveIn.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveIn_RecordingStopped);
writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveIn.WaveFormat);

try
{
    waveIn.StartRecording();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Ошибка точно связана с неправильно заданными параметрами для waveIn. Попробуйте так: `waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);` и уберите строчку `DeviceNumber`

Comment: Установил 'waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);' и убрал 'DeviceNumber' - ошибка осталась.

Comment: чем отличаются компьютеры, на которых работает и на которых не работает код?

Comment: По сути идентичны, даже версия ОС одна и та же стоит. Попробую дрова на звук переставить. На ноутбуке все заработало на раз

Comment: А вы проверяли, микрофон вообще работает не на ноутбуке, если он подключен?

Comment: Переставил драйвера - проблема ушла. Микрофон работал, я его проверял, но при обращении к нему из приложения возникала ошибка.